# new Audio play() gives error until DOOM click in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

I'm trying to play Audio (no video, only audio so I cant use `muted = true`) after 5 seconds after reloading the page, but I get `DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first`. I know why, but I want to know if there is some possibility to do it.

Comment: It's like the error says. Many modern browsers will prohibit the autoplaying of audio/video and instead it must be triggered by a user action.

Answer (score 0):

You just cant play sound in browser unless user has interacted with it. I would suggest to add a start button/popup which user can click thus satisfying the browser [security policy condition](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) and it will play sound.